# comparison of cell arrays of string for piano detect

Tags: string, matlab, comparison

i try make chord piano detection by using matlab language. i able to identify every single tone note and i want to display the result by using string comparison so i make code like this

```
 function akor=readChord(notes) %notes is input String data type
a1={'A' 'C#/Db' 'E'};
b1={'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'};
c1={'C' 'E' 'G'};
d1={'D' 'F#/Gb' 'A'};
e1={'E' 'G#/Ab' 'B'};
f1={'F' 'A' 'C'};
g1={'G' 'A#/Bb' 'D'};
%Chord Minor
a2={'A' 'C' 'E'};
b2={'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'};
c2={'C' 'D#/Eb' 'G'};
d2={'D' 'F' 'A'};
e2={'E' 'G' 'B'};
f2={'F' 'G#/Ab' 'C'};
g2={'G' 'A#/Bb' 'D'};
 a=notes(3,:)
    if v=isempty(setxor(a,a1))==1;
        display('Chord A mayor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,b1))==1;
        display('Chord B')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,c1))==1;
        display('Chord C mayor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,d1))==1;
        display('Chord D mayor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,e1))==1;
        display('Chord E mayor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,f1)==1;
        display('Chord F mayor')
    elseif v = v = isempty(setxor(a,g1)==1;
        display('Chord G mayor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,a2))==1;
        display('Chord A minor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,b2))==1;
        display('Chord B')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,c2))==1;
        display('Chord C minor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,d2))==1;
        display('Chord D minor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,e2))==1;
        display('Chord E minor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,f2)==1;
        display('Chord F minor')
    elseif v = isempty(setxor(a,g2)==1;
        display('Chord G minor')
    else
        display('not Detect')

    end
```

but it look like i have error
Error: File: bacagambar.m Line: 18 Column: 9
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
anyone know what i should did

Comment: have you considered using `switch` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `switch` staement might be more appropriate in this case

```
switch note(3,:)
   case {'A' 'C#/Db' 'E'}
      akor = 'Chord A mayor';
   case {'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'}
      akor = 'Chord B';
   % put all other patters in similar case
   otherwise
      akor = '';
      error('not detected');
end
fprintf( 1, '%s\n', akor );
```