# Can i use input String Array in Switch case Matlab Function?

Tags: string, matlab, switch-statement

i try to make Chord Detection by using string data for my project and i make code like this

```
function akor=NoteAkor(notes)
notes=notes(3,:)
switch notes
   case notes={'A','C#/Db','E'}
      akor = 'Chord A mayor';
   case notes={'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'}
      akor = 'Chord B';
    case notes={'C' 'E' 'G'}
        akor = 'Chord C mayor'
    case notes={'D' 'F#/Gb' 'A'}
        akor = 'Chord D mayor'
    case notes={'E' 'G#/Ab' 'B'}
        akor = 'Chord E mayor'
    case notes={'F' 'A' 'C'}
        akor = 'Chord F mayor'
    case notes={'G' 'A#/Bb' 'D'}
        akor = 'Chord G mayor'
    case notes={'A' 'C' 'E'}
        akor = 'Chord A minor'
    case notes={'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'}
        akor = 'Chord B minor'
    case notes={'C' 'D#/Eb' 'G'}
        akor = 'Chord C minor'
    case notes={'D' 'F' 'A'}
        akor = 'Chord D minor'
    case notes={'E' 'G' 'B'}
        akor = 'Chord E mayor'
    case notes={'F' 'G#/Ab' 'C'}
        akor = 'Chord F mayor'
    case notes={'G' 'A#/Bb' 'D'}
        akor = 'Chord  G mayor'
   % put all other patters in similar case
   otherwise
      akor = '';
      error('not detected');
end
fprintf( 1, '%s\n', akor );
```

but it's Error: File: NoteAkor.m Line: 4 Column: 14
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

anyone can help me to fix my code or maybe give me another way to make this code work?
Thx  before...

Comment: what was wrong with the code I gave you as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17130920/1714410) to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130865/comparison-of-cell-arrays-of-string-for-piano-detect)? The syntax there was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `switch` construct is wrong: You only need to mention the variable name (`notes`) once, after the `switch`. Don't add it after the `case` keywords:

```
switch notes
    case {'A','C#/Db','E'}
        akor = 'Chord A mayor';
   case {'B' 'D' 'F#/Gb'}
       akor = 'Chord B';

...

    otherwise
        akor = '';
        error('not detected');
end
```